# Free to use document-based database

Tags: asp.net, open-source, licensing, ravendb

I wanted to use RavenDB as back-end for my website . but right now when i checked its License I understood that to use RavenDB in a closed source software ( I'm not going to release my website codes ) I should buy a license .

So I can't do that . is there any alternatives to RavenDB without this license limitation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe look at MongoDB.

http://www.mongodb.org/

Comment: Thank you , I read MongoDB licensing issues . but you know , I'm not familiar with licenses . You mean that to use MongoDB in a commercial ,closed source web application there is no need to purchase any license ? just totally free ?

Comment: Im not a Licensing expert either. That being said my understanding of the AGPL license is that you are free to use it unless you make improvements which then must be fed back to the open source project. I cant guarantee this as being the perfect definition of the licence though.  https://github.com/mongodb/mongo